# integrating onesignal in multimodule project android

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

i m getting android failed to choose configuration of the library when i m adding one-signal code in the gradle

this is my app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':letsinternlib')
    compile project(':commonslib')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


}
```

my library gradle is look like i added one signal code in this library 
but it does not sync the comman library in the projects so please take a look

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.7.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(path:':commonslib',configuration: 'default')
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
   // implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running into the same issue as below.
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/9

Until we can resolve the issue you can try removing it by removing the following from your build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.7.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

However without this you may see some errors related to version not matching with gms, firebase, the android support library. To resolve these you can follow this guide:

[OneSignal Documentation: Troubleshooting Android](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android#section-error-all-gms-firesbase-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)